# JMSTemplate and DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I have 2 queues in Redhat ActiveMQ, one is used for consuming and other one for both producing and consuming object messages.

Once consumed from the main queue it is pushed to 2nd queue for further processing, However while using JmsTemplate the messages are getting lost randomly,

I am using same Bean with ActiveMQConnectionFactory on 2 of the DMLC container and with the JmsTemplate

Let me know how to ensure that messages are not getting lost in JmsTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would double check that nobody else check for messages on the queues you have. If there is some sort of development environment where you have several instances of the application running - they might compete for the messages. It could be another developer launching another instance of the app using the same connection string to the ActiveMQ, or dev/stage environments.

Comment: Thanks for the response, However there is no other setup or environments running, The log shows that the message has gone to the 2nd queue, Later its never been deqeued as looks like the message has not gone to the queue, there are no errors either from the ActiveMQ broker during that time. Not sure any additional failover parameter has to be added or anything to do with ActiveMQ ConnectionFactory.

Comment: Got it. Could you post your Connection Factory parameters here?

Comment: @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory()
    {
        final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(user);
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy());
        return connectionFactory;
    }

Comment: @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplateAnotherQueue()    {
        final JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setDefaultDestinationName(anotherQueue);
        template.setSessionTransacted(true);
        template.setConnectionFactory(amqConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

Comment: public void sendAnotherMessage(final MessageObject messageObj) throws JMSException{
   if (messageObj != null)  {
    jmsTemplateanotherQueue.send(new MessageCreator(){
     public Message createMessage(final Session session) throws JMSException
       LOGGER.info("sending obj message");
       ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();
       message.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, Long.valueOf(amqDelay));
       message.setObject(messageObj);
       return message;      }
     }
    }); }

Comment: Could you try to initialize http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.html